# When updating to springboot3.1.1, I can not import ...ElasticSearchRestHealthContributorAutoConfiguration;

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-autoconfiguration, spring-boot-3

When updating to springbootfrom 2 to 3.1.1, I can not import org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.elasticsearch.ElasticSearchRestHealthContributorAutoConfiguration.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.1.1/api/org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/elasticsearch/ElasticsearchRestHealthContributorAutoConfiguration.html#%3Cinit%3E()
But when I check the spring doc, it looks like the class is still here. Not sure how I can fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your import statement.

use this one Instead

```
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchRestHealthContributorAutoConfiguration
```

[image]